# php artisan tinker using homestead on windows pc

Tags: php, laravel

is it possible to run laravel's artisan tinker on my windows computer? Actually it's writing me

```
Boris repl not supported. Needs readline, posix, and pcntl extensions.
```

And I saw that php readline doesn't support windows, but I'm confused because my virtual machine is ubuntu, so I have no idea if it can work and how to install those extensions.

Comment: You should be able to SSH into the Homestead box - then run any command from the command line there

Comment: if I type vagrant up, then vagrant ssh it's still showing same error